# C# e MySQL com AspNetUsers, tabelas apagadas

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com C# (MVC) e MySQL. Tudo funciona perfeitamente bem quando utilizo minha instância local do Banco de Dados.

Eu dupliquei este banco de dados no UolHost e é aí que acontece algo bizarro.
Quando eu mudo a connection string (apenas o endereço) para se conectar ao banco do UolHost, ao tentar logar no sistema, todas as tabelas do banco são apagadas e são criadas novas tabelas `AspNetUsers` automaticamente.

Porque o sistema está apagando o banco de dados e construindo apenas estas tabelas? E porque isso só acontece no banco de dados do servidor, enquanto que na máquina funciona normalmente?

Alguém, por favor, teria uma dica?

Comment: Você está usando Simple Membership?

Comment: Esta situação ocorre após você publicar o site? Verifique se não está enviando o banco de dados mais de uma vez.

Comment: Eu nem chego a publicar... só de rodar no VS isso já acontece...

Comment: Cigano, estou usando a autenticação que o próprio VS coloca quando você cria o projeto...

Answer (score 1):

Creio que deve estar usando o EntityFramework. Essa coisa bizarra pode vir dele, por causa da configuração ao inicializar um banco de dados. Tem quatro opções para inicializar o banco de dados:

1. **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists** - Esse é o *default*, e cria o banco de dados caso não existe
2. **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges** - Esse modo *dropa* o *banco de dados completo* se os modelos foram modificados.
3. **DropCreateDatabaseAlways** - Esse moda *dropa* o *banco de dados completo* **sempre**.
4. **Personalizado** - Pode criar seu próprio inicializador se um desses não satisfaz

Verifique se está usando algo como o **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges**, pois é capaz do sistema achar que os modelos mudaram quando você muda o seu *connection string*.

Procure uma função chamada:

```
.SetInitializer<T>()
```

Comment: Não era bem isso, mas sua dica me ajudou a descobrir!!! Valeu!!!

Comment: @FelipeBulle Que bom! Se quiser, pode postar uma resposta com qual era a solução mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

O problema era que a tabela __migrationhistory estava com letras maiúsculas no banco... e como não era encontrado no InitializeDatabase, ele limpava e criava novamente!

```
var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
            string.Format(
              "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__migrationhistory'",
              "superacrm"));

            // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
            if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
            }
```